# Excel - How can I find the last column with a value and pull the corresponding column header?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table with a column containing distinct `IDs` and then some boolean columns with `1s and 0s`. For each row (ID), I'm looking for a formula to find the last boolean column with a value of `1` and then pull the corresponding column header. I've added a screenshot of the input (blue columns) and the desired output (yellow column). I think I can use the `offset` formula for pulling the column headers but can't figure out how to determine the last boolean column with a `1`.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Use `LOOKUP()` or `XLOOKUP()` depending on your version of Excel. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried `xlookup` as `=XLOOKUP(1, <cell range of 1s and 0s to search>, <cell range of column headers>)` but this always gives me `Day 1` for every row

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that table has its top-left cell in `A1`, In `I2`:

`=XLOOKUP(1,B2:H2,B$1:H$1,,,-1)`

Or, non-365:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/B2:H2,B$1:H$1)`

and copy down.

Comment: That's great, works like a charm! I was using `XLOOKUP` but wasn't implementing it correctly. Thanks for this!